# error in arraylist within loop java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple calculator but I'm getting an error. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvInput;
String textcontent = "";
String input = "";
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Character> operator = new ArrayList<Character>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvInput= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_input);
}


public void btn1(View view) {
    input = input + "1";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}

public void btn3(View view) {
    input = input + "3";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}

public void btn2(View view) {
    input = input + "2";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}


public void btn0(View view) {
    input = input + "0";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}

public void btn7(View view) {
    input = input + "7";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}

public void btn8(View view) {
    input = input + "8";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}
public void btn9(View view) {
    input = input + "9";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}
public void btn5(View view) {
    input = input + "5";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}
public void btn6(View view) {
    input = input + "6";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}
public void btnSub(View view) {
    number.add(Integer.parseInt(tvInput.getText().toString()));
    tvInput.setText("-");
    operator.add('-');
    input = "";
}
public void btnMul(View view) {
    number.add(Integer.parseInt(tvInput.getText().toString()));
    tvInput.setText("*");
    operator.add('*');
    input = "";
}
public void btnDiv(View view) {
    number.add(Integer.parseInt(tvInput.getText().toString()));
    tvInput.setText("/");
    operator.add('/');
    input = "";
}
public void btn4(View view) {
    input = input + "4";
    tvInput.setText(input);
}
public void btnAdd(View view) {
    number.add(Integer.parseInt(tvInput.getText().toString()));
    tvInput.setText("+");
    operator.add('+');
    input = "";
}
public void btnEqual(View view) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= number.size(); i++) {
        result = number.get(i - 1);
       if(operator.get(i - 1) == '+')
         result = result+number.get(i);  //error is here
        tvInput.setText("" + result);
    }
    }
}
```

I think that error because change var of result within loop ..

This is the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick

Where is the problem?
What's the solution?

Comment: I don't see any onClick method in your code; it might be required. Maybe consider to post the whole stacktrace instead of just the part you think might be crucial

Comment: please attach your whole error stack trace. But I have a feeling the issue is with the way youre connecting the `onclick` of your buttons in the xml file. you should have something like   `onClick="btn1()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because of `ArrayIndexOutofBound` at last index in below code

```
result=result+number.get(i);
```

In for loop you have stared i form 1 , through `i<=number.size()` and you are taking value by using (i-1) but in above line you directly taking value so when loop reached to last position it dose not having last element .Use below code to do this your operation.

```
public void btnEqual(View view) {
    int result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<number.size();i++){
        result=number.get(i);
       if(operator.get(i)=='+')
         result=result+number.get(i);  //error is here
         tvInput.setText(""+result);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to change my display method from this:

```
   private void DisplayB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(score);
```

to this :

```
   private void DisplayB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

I hope this helps you.